# Smarty adding if condition in foreach to separate LI into multiple UL

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, smarty

Little new to smarty but think ive done ok getting this far, so i have a foreach which makes my menu which works great however the generated list items is too long for the menu so want to split the menus into separate lists every 10 for example but cannot seem to crack it? anyone have any ideas?

Code i have so far:

```
{foreach from=$item1.$childs item="item2" name="item2"}

    {if $smarty.foreach.item2.index % 10 == 0}
        <ul class="menu-col">
    {/if}

    {assign var="item_url2" value=$item2|fn_form_dropdown_object_link:$block.type}
        <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item{if $item2.active || $item2|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} ty-menu__submenu-item-active{/if}{if $item2.class} {$item2.class}{/if}">
            <a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" {if $item_url2} href="{$item_url2}"{/if}>{$item2.$name}</a>
        </li>

     {if $smarty.foreach.item2.index % 10 == 0}
         </ul>
     {/if}

 {/foreach}
```

however it seems to generate like this:

```
    <ul class="menu-col">

    <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item ty-menu__submenu-item-active">
    <a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/vip-air-mesh/">VIP (Air Mesh)</a>
    </li>

</ul>

<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/vip-bonded-pu-leather/">VIP (Bonded PU Leather)</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/vip-vintage-denim/">VIP (Vintage Denim)</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/zen-lounger/">Zen Lounger</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/acoustic-sofa/">Acoustic Sofa</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/avatar-lounger/">Avatar Lounger</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/butterfly-sofa/">Butterfly Sofa</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/the-boss/">The Boss</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/wing-ottoman/">Wing Ottoman</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/conversion-lounger/">Conversion Lounger</a>
</li>

<ul class="menu-col">

    <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
    <a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/evolution-sofa/">Evolution Sofa</a>
    </li>

</ul>

<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/fiorenze-leather-sofa/">Fiorenze Leather Sofa</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/ottomans/">Ottomans</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/roma-sofa/">Roma Sofa</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/snugg-sofa/">SNUGG Sofa</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/space-pod/">Space Pod</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/studio-lounger/">Studio Lounger</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/tech-pillow-rest-pad/">Tech Pillow Rest Pad</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/tivoli-lounger/">Tivoli Lounger</a>
</li>
<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/twin-couch-sofa/">Twin Couch Sofa</a>
</li>

<ul class="menu-col">

    <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
    <a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/versa-table/">Versa Table</a>
    </li>

</ul>

<li class="ty-menu__submenu-item">
<a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" href="/interior-bean-bags/cloudchair/">Cloudchair (Air Mesh)</a>
</li>
```

but i need it like

```
<ul>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try by using the [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function at your php side before sending the menu array to smarty view. Suppose you have 13 menus then this function will divide your menu array into nested array one with of 10, and remaining 3, so you can iterate over this at smarty side easily.

Comment: sorry, i cant really change the core php as its a software so upgrading would break it.

Comment: Can you please send the array structure here for your menu , may be after that it will be more clear and will try to help you

Comment: sorry new to php / smarty anyway i can output the array?

Comment: Okay that will also do. Copy the output of the array and paste in your question by editing it,

Comment: to be honest not sure how... lol sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the opening and closing main ul outside the foreach and then add a condition to restart it if the current iteration is a multiple of 10 and it's not the last value (so you don't end with an empty ul if the array has exactly 10 values)

```
<ul class="menu-col">
    {foreach from=$item1.$childs item="item2" name="item2"}

        {if $smarty.foreach.item2.iteration % 10 == 0 && !$smarty.foreach.item2.last}
            </ul>
            <ul class="menu-col">
        {/if}

        {assign var="item_url2" value=$item2|fn_form_dropdown_object_link:$block.type}
            <li class="ty-menu__submenu-item{if $item2.active || $item2|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} ty-menu__submenu-item-active{/if}{if $item2.class} {$item2.class}{/if}">
                <a class="ty-menu__submenu-link" {if $item_url2} href="{$item_url2}"{/if}>{$item2.$name}</a>
            </li>

     {/foreach}
</ul>
```